# Azure recycling references after long inactivity

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I am using Azure Cloud Service and have Web and Worker roles. Web role serves static HTML/JS/CSS files and Worker role runs WebAPI code with OWIN hosting it.

When I publish the service, everything works fine if it is being used instantly.
But after some time of inactivity, it serves all the request that do NOT need dependencies, but fails to serve all other ones.

E.g. I have a SimpleController that inherits ApiController and CustomController that inherits MyController connects which to DB and I have it in my Core DLL that I am referencing.

After some inactivity, SimpleController that inherits ApiController works like a charm.
But MyController, the one that has base class in another DLL does not work anymore.

I think Azure might be recycling the role and it's references somehow because of inactivity and rebuilding only the main role DLL (with all system DLLs available), but not custom references.

I have all custom references property CopyLocal set to True and it works just after the publish, so this problem should not be the one..

Any ideas how can I debug this type of scenario?

P.S. I've been debuging the non-working controller and it actually calls controller of MyController class, but fails when it has to go to base controller that connects to DB.

Comment: Could you please paste what errors/exceptions you met.

Comment: I'd guess that what happens between "okay" and "not okay" states is that the application pool is restarted and your code is designed such way that it can't survive this. You can easily check that the recycle does happen by adding tracing into `Application_Start()` and `Application_End()`.

Comment: The code can survive recycling just fine, until it has all the references that it had for the first time it ran. I will try tracing with Global.asax Application_Start() and Application_End(), but it does not identify problem still.